# How to get a key press to correspond to the function that gets called first in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, dom, keylistener

So I'm trying something out, if you have two functions you want to call after the same key press like so:

```js
    var plus = function () {
    document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
        if (/[+]/g.test(e.key)) {
            console.log("plus");
        }
    })
    }

    plus();

    var minus = function() {
        document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
            if (/[-]/g.test(e.key)) {
                console.log("minus");
            }
        });
    }

    minus();

    function check() {
        document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
            if(plus) {
                if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                    console.log("enter pressed after plus");
                    plus = false;
                    minus = function() {
                        document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
                            if (/[-]/g.test(e.key)) {
                                console.log("minus");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            } else if(minus) {
                if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                    console.log("enter pressed after minus");
                    minus = false;
                    plus = function () {
                        document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
                            if (/[+]/g.test(e.key)) {
                                console.log("plus");
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }

            }
        });
    }

    check();
```

If you press minus first then enter `console.log("enter pressed after plus")` always gets called first because of the code's order, even though what I want to do is that I want the enter to correspond to the key I'm pressing first, if I press plus first then I want `console.log("enter pressed after plus")` to get called, and if I press minus first then I want `console.log("enter pressed after minus")` to get called.

Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Oh also sorry about the stupid title, couldn't think of a better one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clean this up a bit (keep it [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)) you can move all the event handler logic into a single function and use a single listener.

To keep track of the last pressed key we can use a [variable defined in the function's outer scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Getting_Data_Into_an_Event_Listener_Using_the_Outer_Scope_Property). And, update it after each event. Then, when "Enter" is pressed we can check what the last key was and log accordingly.

---

Also, the [`KeyboardEvent.keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) property is depreciated. You should use [`KeyboardEvent.code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) property instead.

---

### Example

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input')
const log = document.getElementById('log')

function check() {
  let lastKey = null

  input.addEventListener('keyup', ({ key }) => {
    if (['+', '-', 'Enter'].includes(key)) { // we only care about these keys
      if (key === '+') log.textContent = 'plus'
      if (key === '-') log.textContent = 'minus'
      if (key === 'Enter') { // `Enter` was keyed, what was keyed last?
        if (lastKey === '+') log.textContent = 'enter pressed after plus'
        if (lastKey === '-') log.textContent = 'enter pressed after minus'
      }

      lastKey = key // current key becomes last key
    }
  })
}

check()
```

```html
<input placeholder="Click here, then press and release a key." size="40">
<p id="log"></p>
```

---

Comment: Thanks a lot, really I can't thank you enough. The whole point of this was to implement it in an application I'm making so thanks a lot.

Comment: @AliMohamed, no problem!